# Are "tf.nn.relu(A)" and "tf.maximum(A, 0)" the same?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here are two codes.

```
tf.nn.relu("output of previous layer")

tf.maximum("output of previous layer", 0)
```

Do these two behave exactly the same?

In other words, is it possible to replace one with the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once relu is defined as:

```
max(features, 0)
```

they are basically the same. Both take a tensor as input and return a tensor. The only difference is the supported types.

The `tf.nn.relu` supports the following types:

- `float32`, `float64`, `int32`, `uint8`, `int16`, `int8`, `int64`, `bfloat16`, `uint16`, `half`, `uint32`, `uint64`, `qint8`

while  `tf.maximum` supports a subset of the above types:

- `half`, `float32`, `float64`, `int32`, `int64`

Comment: Thank you. Can one replace the other completely? During the learning, is there any error in Differential calculation?

Comment: You're welcome! As far as I know, you could replace one for the other (although I don't think in any reason for this) and this wouldn't interfere in error calculation.